# How can I make touch events pass through a UIView (similar to pointer-events:none in CSS)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uikit

In CSS, `pointer-events:none;` allows click events to pass through an element. I'm curious if there is anything similar that I can do in Objective-C on iOS for `UIView`s.

[Here's a jsfiddle to an example of pointer-events: none.](http://jsfiddle.net/yz5M2/)

**Could I somehow achieve the same behavior for a** `UIView` **by overriding** `hitTest:withEvent:`**?** Or maybe there is another way to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is commonly called "Event Bubbling".

You may refer to the Apple docs here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/understanding_event_handling_responders_and_the_responder_chain

So your basic instinct was right, you in fact do need utilize `hitTest:withEvent:`, but you can further customize things by hooking up into the Responder chain. That section has a very neat example.

Comment: The link is dead, you could refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html .

Comment: Now the replacement link is dead, here is a working one as of today:  [Understanding Responders and the Responder Chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/HandlngEventsUsingtheResponderChain.html)

Comment: Here's the newest link: [Understanding Event Handling, Responders, and the Responder Chain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/understanding_event_handling_responders_and_the_responder_chain)

Answer (score 12):

Here's a handy implementation in line with your initial intuition:

```
#import "TouchTransparentView.h"

@implementation TouchTransparentView

-(id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    id hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView == self) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return hitView;
    }
}

@end
```

Swift version, with a @IB upgrade

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class PassthroughTouchView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var passthroughTouchEvents : Bool = false

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        if hitView == self && passthroughTouchEvents == true {
            return nil;
        } else {
            return hitView;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: set view class in IB to ours]
[image: toggle now accessible in IB]

Answer (score 3):

In swift:

```
import UIKit

class PassThroughView: UIView {

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)

        if hitView == self {
            return nil
        } else {
            return hitView
        }
    }
}
```

But having to do this kind of sucks...

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking for something that acts like `pointer-events:none` I would use

```
yourView.userInteractionEnabled = NO
```

It should do basically the same thing.

Comment: This kills events; they don't make it through to children. This isn't what OP was looking for.