# How to allow a CLICK, through a UITableView, to buttons behind?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, event-bubbling

Imagine a large table view that's mostly transparent, with some elements here and there. (Perhaps there's a large gap between cells, or, picture the cells being mainly transparent with only a couple buttons or such.

Behind this mostly-transparent table is some other materials, say with some buttons.

How to make the table that

- if you scroll it scrolls normally
- if you tap on a button on a cell, that works normally
- but if you tap on one of the buttons behind the table, the click is passed through and affects that button?

(By "click" I mean what we now call a "primary action triggered" - a "click on a UIButton".)

There are a number of different well-known techniques for passing touches (as such) through views in different situations,

- [Pass touches through a UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53922625/294884)
- [How can I make touch events pass through a UIView (similar to pointer-events:none in CSS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25044511/294884)

etc.

But I've never been able to get the above three mentioned conditions working.

Summary: enable clicking on a UIButton behind a UITableView.

The "background" buttons should work fully correctly as buttons in all phases, ie if you eg. hold down but then slide off.

Is there a way?

---

It occurs to me that passing clicks through a scroll view, to buttons behind, is an almost identical problem.

Comment: Do you want to support row selection? What else in the table view cells do you want to support interaction with besides some possible `UIButton` instances? If there anything else besides `UIButton` instances behind the table view you need to support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code demonstrates the ability to have a table view with a transparent background that allows you to tap on controls in the table view rows, it allows the table view to be scrolled, it allows table view rows to be selected, and it allows for controls behind the table view to be tapped as long as the tap is outside of any controls in a table view row.

The demonstration makes use of modern cell configuration using a custom `UIContentConfiguration` and custom `UIContentView` (modeled after [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63091539/20287183)). It also makes use of a custom `UITableView` subclass.

Both the custom table view subclass and the custom cell content view implement custom hit testing based on the solution provided by [Pass touches through a UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53922625/294884) but with some modification.

Begin by creating a new iOS app project. Setup the project to be based on Swift and Storyboard.

The following code contains lots of comments. The majority of the code below is to setup a working demonstration. The important code is the custom `hitTest` method in `PassTableView` and `ButtonContentView`. Just about everything can be changed as needed except those two methods. Note that the implementation doesn't depend on the table view transparency. That just allows you to see the controls behind the table view.

Add a new Swift file named `PassTableView.swift` with the following contents:

```swift
import UIKit

// This subclass of UITableView allows touches to be delegated to another view.
// Only touches that are not used by the cell contents are delegated.
// The table view cells also need to implement the same logic.
// Having the logic in both the cells and the table view allows touches to be delegated if the
// user taps on a cell or if the user taps on an area of the table view not covered by a cell.
class PassTableView: UITableView {
    weak var touchDelegate: UIView? = nil

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        guard let view = super.hitTest(point, with: event) else {
            return nil
        }

        guard view === self, let point = touchDelegate?.convert(point, from: self) else {
            return view
        }

        // If the passthrough view returns a specific view then return that subview
        // If the passthrough view returns itself, then return the view that would normally be returned.
        // Without that last test, table view scrolling and cell selection is disabled.
        if let subview = touchDelegate?.hitTest(point, with: event), subview !== touchDelegate {
            return subview
        } else {
            return view
        }
    }
}
```

Add another Swift file named `ButtonCell.swift` with the following contents:

```swift
import UIKit

fileprivate class ButtonCellView: UIView, UIContentView {
    var configuration: UIContentConfiguration {
        didSet {
            configure(configuration: configuration)
        }
    }

    private var button = UIButton()

    init(configuration: UIContentConfiguration) {
        self.configuration = configuration

        super.init(frame: .zero)

        // Give the cell content a semi-transparent background
        // This depends on the table view having a clear background
        // Optionally, set this to .clear and give the table view a transparent background
        backgroundColor = .systemBackground.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

        let cfg = UIButton.Configuration.borderedTinted()
        button = UIButton(configuration: cfg, primaryAction: UIAction(handler: { action in
            print("Button \(self.button.configuration?.title ?? "?") tapped")
        }))
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(button)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func configure(configuration: UIContentConfiguration) {
        guard let configuration = configuration as? ButtonCellConfiguration else { return }

        touchDelegate = configuration.touchDelegate
        
        var cfg = button.configuration
        cfg?.title = configuration.title
        button.configuration = cfg
    }

    weak var touchDelegate: UIView? = nil

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        guard let view = super.hitTest(point, with: event) else {
            return nil
        }

        guard view === self, let point = touchDelegate?.convert(point, from: self) else {
            return view
        }

        // If the passthrough view returns a specific view then return that subview
        // If the passthrough view returns itself, then return the view that would normally be returned.
        // Without that last test, table view scrolling and cell selection is disabled.
        if let subview = touchDelegate?.hitTest(point, with: event), subview !== touchDelegate {
            return subview
        } else {
            return view
        }
    }
}

struct ButtonCellConfiguration: UIContentConfiguration {
    var title: String // Used as the button title
    weak var touchDelegate: UIView? = nil // The passthrough view to pass touches to

    func makeContentView() -> UIView & UIContentView {
        return ButtonCellView(configuration: self)
    }
    
    func updated(for state: UIConfigurationState) -> ButtonCellConfiguration {
        return self
    }
}
```

Last, replace the contents of the provided `ViewController.swift` with the following:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // Use the custom table view subclass so we can support custom hit testing
    private lazy var tableView: PassTableView = {
        let tv = PassTableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        tv.dataSource = self
        tv.delegate = self
        tv.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "buttonCell")
        tv.allowsSelection = true
        return tv
    }()

    // This view acts as the touch delegate for the table view and the cell content.
    // This view should contain all of the controls you need to handle behind the transparent table view.
    // You need to use this extra view since using the table view's superview (self.view)
    // as the touch delegate results in infinite recursion in the hitTests.
    private lazy var viewLayer: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .systemRed // Pick a color

        // Fill the view controller with the view layer. Adjust as desired.
        viewLayer.frame = view.bounds
        viewLayer.autoresizingMask = [ .flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight ]
        view.addSubview(viewLayer)

        // Add two buttons to the view layer
        // The first will be behind rows of the tableview
        var cfg = UIButton.Configuration.borderedTinted()
        cfg.title = "Background1"
        let button1 = UIButton(configuration: cfg, primaryAction: UIAction(handler: { action in
            print("Background1 button tapped")
        }))
        button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewLayer.addSubview(button1)

        // The second button will be below the last row (on most devices) but still behind the table view.
        // This lets us test touch delegation for buttons behind a row in the table view and for buttons
        // behind just the table view.
        cfg = UIButton.Configuration.borderedTinted()
        cfg.title = "Background2"
        let button2 = UIButton(configuration: cfg, primaryAction: UIAction(handler: { action in
            print("Background2 button tapped")
        }))
        button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewLayer.addSubview(button2)

        // Position the two background buttons
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewLayer.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
            button1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewLayer.centerYAnchor),
            button2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewLayer.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
            button2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewLayer.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        ])

        // Setup the table view's touch delegate
        tableView.touchDelegate = self.viewLayer
        // Either set the table view background to clear and the cell content to some transparent color, or
        // set the table view background to a transparent color and the cell content to clear.
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        // Fill the view controller with the table view. Adjust as desired.
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
        tableView.autoresizingMask = [ .flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight ]
        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10 // Partially fill the table view with rows (on most devices). Change as needed.
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "buttonCell", for: indexPath)

        // Use modern cell configuration
        // This is where we set the cell's button title and touch delegate
        let cfg = ButtonCellConfiguration(title: "Button \(indexPath.row)", touchDelegate: self.viewLayer)
        cell.contentConfiguration = cfg
        // Ensure the cell has a clear background
        cell.backgroundConfiguration = .clear()

        return cell
    }

    // Demonstrate that cell selection still works as long as the user does not tap on
    // any buttons (on the cells or behind the table view).
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Selected row \(indexPath)")

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

The code supports iOS 15+. Adjust your app's deployment target as needed.

Build and run the app. You will see a table view with 10 rows, each containing a button. You will also see two other buttons labeled "Background ButtonX". The two extra buttons are behind the transparent table view.

All table view interactions work as expected including scrolling and cell selection. Tapping any button, including the two behind the table view, will print a message to the console.

I already state this in the code comments but it is worth repeating. It's critical that the view passed to the `touchDelegate` used by the table view and the cells must not be in the table view's superview hierarchy, such as `self.view`. The `touchDelegate` must be a sibling (or cousin) view. Violating this condition will lead to infinite recursion when tapping outside of a control in a cell.

---

This general solution also works with `UIScrollView`. Create a `PassScrollView` subclass with the same code as `PassTableView`. That's it. It's much simpler since you don't need to deal with table cells.

```swift
import UIKit

// This subclass of UIScrollView allows touches to be delegated to another view.
// This allows touches to be delegated if the user taps anywhere within
// the scroll view that doesn't contain a control or other view.
class PassScrollView: UIScrollView {
    weak var touchDelegate: UIView? = nil

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        guard let view = super.hitTest(point, with: event) else {
            return nil
        }

        guard view === self, let point = touchDelegate?.convert(point, from: self) else {
            return view
        }

        // If the passthrough view returns a specific view then return that subview
        // If the passthrough view returns itself, then return the view that would normally be returned.
        // Without that last test, scrolling is disabled.
        if let subview = touchDelegate?.hitTest(point, with: event), subview !== touchDelegate {
            return subview
        } else {
            return view
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow!  loving the `UIContentConfiguration` to begin with ...

Comment: Mind-boggling solution. See answer added! To dive right in, one question....You mention where to use clear/tr etc colors in the different levels (ie, so that, purely aesthetically, one can indeed see-through the table). Just TBTC I assume that whether clear is/isn't used has no affect whatsoever on whether the system works, am I correct? ie the system works perfectly even if (for some reason) you made everything black: the color issues you mention are purely aesthetic. That's correct? (Indeed I tried it and as expected it makes no difference; just checking this point!)

Comment: Yes, the colors I used were purely to make the table view transparent allowing you to see the two buttons behind the table view.

Comment: @Fattie I updated the end of the answer to show how you can use this solution if you just want to work with a scroll view instead of a table view.

Comment: RIght, there's definitely something going on since a UITableView is just .. a UIScrollView!  That minimal of a solution doesn't work in the table view class. Perhaps in fact that solution for scroll view, actually wouldn't work if you happened to add a button in the scroll view.

Comment: A table view is far more than just a scroll view. The table view adds a whole set of view in the scroll view - the table cells. The cells are a whole other level of views that need to be worked around to allow the touches to be handled. The scroll view solution I added to my answer does work if you add buttons to the scroll view. That's the whole point of the custom `hitTest`. The buttons in the scroll view get their touches handled first. Only if your tap in an "empty" area of the scroll view would anything behind the scroll view get its chance.

Comment: Right, but a table view is just a direct subclass of a scroll view - with more views added.  *The scroll view solution I added to my answer does work if you add buttons to the scroll view* - ah, that's great.  I think you've explained the diff in your other comment ...

Answer (score 0):

Wow just wow.

Here's a demo of the mind-blowing @HangarRash Solution:

[image]

Here is the complete Xcode project:

> https://ufile.io/a3jkcdj2 <sup>†</sup>

[image]

##### *Interesting further issue:*

Go to the view controller. Notice I set up some storyboard cells, which use the @HangarRash Technology™

Just toggle the code to use the storyboard cells ...

[image]

(Or use code like `if indexPath.item % 3 == 0 ...` to show a few of both cells on screen at the same time.)

Notice "my" cells **don't quite work** in all situations.

I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong, as the HR solution is clear and I seem to be implementing the steps needed. Maybe someone can see the issue.

Incredible solution! Note in particular the HR solution even achieves the "further challenge" mentioned at the end of the question.

---

<sup>†</sup> *zip file download link may expire in 30 days - I know nothing about the web and file sharing - feel free to repost freely or edit this post or link freely*

Comment: A while after I posted my answer I spent a few minutes trying to make my solution work with old-style `UITableViewCell` subclasses. I couldn't get it work (though I didn't try too hard yet). With the custom cell subclass overriding `hitTest`, it turned out that other internal subviews of the cell were intercepting the touches. This wasn't an issue using the modern content configuration approach.

Comment: @HangarRash how interesting so your code in ButtonCell.swift seems to be affecting both the cell itself and the button(s) perhaps?

Comment: @HangarRash I think I worked it out. I tried making the buttons I use (in the conventional cell) have the same hitTest code (I just pass in the touch delegate from the cell).  This then sort of fixes it *for the button* in the cell.  however the other areas (background area) of the cell behaves incorrectly. It could be that the contentView has to have "your fix" applied to it? Perhaps its' the case that your code in ButtonCell.swift in fact does that, IDK.  Investigating!

Comment: Hmm, nope, i really couldn't get that to work either ... it seems that your code in ButtonCell.swift applies it to the "whole" cell in some sense.

Comment: The issue with adding the overridden `hitTest` to a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass is that it just results in an internal content view in the cell getting the touches so the logic doesn't reach the views behind the table view. By using the modern cell code, you are providing that content view class which has the overridden `hitTest`.